# get list of objects distinct by all fields

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I get all the distinct objects in a list using java 8 streams? It has to compare all the fields of objects with each other. For example

`Person a = Person("nameA", "35")` and 
`Person b = Person("nameA", "35")`

should be equal. 
What I've attempted   `personList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())` is returning a list of 2 persons, instead of only 1.

Comment: Your Person class must override equals.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java

Comment: @Eran I've tried overriding equals, but seems like distinct() doesn't use equals() because it's not working. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @Nazerke you most likely didn't override `equals` and `hashcode` correctly. I've provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can you rely on the `equals` and `hashCode` method of the `Person` class like @Eran wrote in the comment, then you can use your code and it will do the job as intended. If you cannot change the `Person` class for some reason, then you need to use a collector with "group by" and specify your key.

Here is an example of how to use "group by" to create your own grouping key:

```
Person person1 = new Person("John", "Doe");
Person person2 = new Person("John", "Doe");
Person person3 = new Person("Mary", "Doe");
Person person4 = new Person("Mary", "Doe");
Person person5 = new Person("john", "Smith");
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3, person4, person5);

// Creates your own equality using "group by". Here we are using first and last name concatenation
final Map<String, List<Person>> collect = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getFirstName() + o.getLastName()));
// Get the values and extract the first element to build a distinct list.
final List<Person> collect1 = collect.values().stream().map(ps -> ps.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect1.size());
```

This prints out:

```
3
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to group by concatenation.  "al" + "andrews" equals "alan" + "drews".  If you have to go this route, it's better to group by `Arrays.asList(first, last)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to override `equals` and `hashcode` to get the expected result.

Example:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String theOtherField; 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        return (name != null ? name.equals(person.name) : person.name == null) && 
                (theOtherField != null ? theOtherField.equals(person.theOtherField) : 
                        person.theOtherField == null);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (theOtherField != null ? theOtherField.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public Person(String name, String theOtherField) {
        this.name = name;
        this.theOtherField = theOtherField;
    }
}
```

Now, assuming you have a list of people like this for example:

```
 List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(new Person("nameA", "35"),
               new  Person("nameA", "35"));
```

Performing the `distinct` operation should yield a list with one element.

```
List<Person> distinctPeople = 
           personList.stream()
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or you can collect to a `Set` implementation without using `distinct` like this:

```
 Set<Person> distinctPeople = new HashSet<>(personList);
```

Note, I've named one of the properties in the `Person` class `theOtherField` because I don't know whether it represents the person's age or not as ideally a person's age should be an `int` not `String`.